# Xslt sorting all data

Tags: xslt

Heey, I have just started learning xslt I have reached problem.
I have xml file like :

```
<projects>
<project nr="1">
<description>z</description>
<description>a</description>
</project>
</projects>
```

There are few projects like that with few descriptions, and what I'm trying to do is to create a html table with all sorted descriptions from all projects. Overall, so If I have 5 projects with 2 description there would be 10 sorted rows. As far I have managed just to sort the first descriptions from all projects, no idea how to include the second and if there would be third fourth etc.
Any clues? Thanks for help.

@edit
So far I have started with flat file, but that doesn't matter. well as of now I have

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="projects">
<xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:sort select="description" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="project">
 Description: <xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
<xsl:text>
 </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
```

I have been messing around with for:each loops however I'm not sure how this should be done to be honest

Comment: Can you post the xsl you have partially working so far?  What have you tried to include multiple projects?

Comment: Do you want to sort all descriptions irrelevant of their projects, or do you want the projects sorted by multiple keys (i.e. by description 1, then if the description1 of two projects is the same by description 2, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/description">
    <xsl:sort/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (based on the provided one and extended):

```
<projects>
    <project nr="1">
        <description>z</description>
        <description>a</description>
    </project>
    <project nr="2">
        <description>b</description>
        <description>y</description>
    </project>
    <project nr="3">
        <description>c</description>
        <description>x</description>
    </project>
    <project nr="4">
        <description>d</description>
        <description>w</description>
    </project>
    <project nr="5">
        <description>e</description>
        <description>u</description>
    </project>
</projects>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<projects>
   <description>a</description>
   <description>b</description>
   <description>c</description>
   <description>d</description>
   <description>e</description>
   <description>u</description>
   <description>w</description>
   <description>x</description>
   <description>y</description>
   <description>z</description>
</projects>
```

Comment: Thanks its working, however the rows are "connected" I couldn't manage to get every description in a new row, and I'm not quite sure how does that work.

Comment: @user2141889, Different XSLT processors treat whitespace preservation differently. As you see from this answer, I get every `description` element on a separate row. This is due to the `<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>` instruction. It is likely that you aren't using this instruction in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you want to use a for-each loop, something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//project/description">
      <xsl:sort select="." />
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will return all of the `<description>` nodes from all projects, sorted in ascending order.  If you want to return a non-xml representation of them, you can replace the `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` node with `Description: <xsl:value-of select="."/>` or whatever you like.